# Vertical Spacing Before and After "Cases" Environment

Tags: amsmath, texshop, cases, mathtools

I'm using TexShop on macOS and I'm hoping someone could tell me how to increase the spacing before and after the *cases* environment as below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[margin=2.9cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand*{\proofname}{Solution}

\newtheorem{innercustomthm}{Problem}
\newenvironment{customthm}[1]
  {\renewcommand\theinnercustomthm{#1}\innercustomthm}
  {\endinnercustomthm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{customthm}{1}\label{one} 
        Find a power series solution in powers of $x$. Show the details.
            \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
                \item $y''-y'+xy=0$
                \item $y''+(1+x^{2})y=0$
            \end{enumerate}
    \end{customthm}

    \begin{proof}
        Suppose $y$ is an analytic function. Then 
            \begin{alignat*}{1}
                y   =\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n},\quad
                y'  =\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n-1},\quad \text{and}\quad
                y'' =\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n-2},\tag{$\star$}
            \end{alignat*}
        give 
            \begin{alignat*}{5}
                &&\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_{}x^{n-2}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n-1}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+1}&=0\\
                &\implies&2a_{2}-a_{1}+\sum\limits_{n=3}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n-2}-\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n-1}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+1}&=0\\
                &\implies&2a_{2}-a_{1}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+3)(n+2)a_{n+3}x^{n+1}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)a_{n+2}x^{n+1}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+1}&=0\\
                &\implies&2a_{2}-a_{1}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left((n+3)(n+2)a_{n+3}-(n+2)a_{n+2}+a_{n}\right)x^{n+1}&=0,
            \end{alignat*}
        whence we obtain the recurrence
            \[
                \begin{cases}
                    \begin{aligned}
                        2a_{2}-a_{1}&=0\\
                        (n+3)(n+2)a_{n+3}-(n+2)a_{n+2}+a_{n}&=0.
                    \end{aligned}
                \end{cases}
            \]
        Solving for the first few terms, we get
            \begin{align*}
                y(x)&=a_{0}\left( 1-\frac{1}{3!}x^{3}-\frac{1}{4!}x^{4}-\frac{1}{5!}x^{5}+\frac{3}{6!}x^{6}+\frac{8}{7!}x^{7}+\frac{14}{8!}x^{8}+\hdots \right)\\
                      &\quad+a_{1}\left( x+\frac{1}{2!}x^{2}+\frac{1}{3!}x^{3}-\frac{1}{4!}x^{4}-\frac{4}{5!}x^{5}-\frac{8}{6!}x^{6}-\frac{3}{7!}x^{7}+\frac{21}{8!}x^{8}\hdots \right).\tag*{\qedhere}
            \end{align*}
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Edit: For those not familiar with amsart, the vertical spacing specified for the "cases" environment is different than the vertical spacing amongst the other lines/equations. **This question is asking how to make this spacing the same**. The spacing is indeed different, unlike what is suggested in the comments, as explained by the accepted answer.

Comment: Please extend your code snipped to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: You really need to cleanup your preamble! Take a time for this. Some of them are not needed (´`\epspdf`, `graphics`, ...)  etc. And please reduce your document example to your problem only. BTW, as far as I see, `cases` has the same distances from text as other math expressions.

Comment: @Zarko It's really not the same. Look closer and see answer below.

Comment: Yes, it is the same. Answer, to which you refer as proof your claim, just show how to increase this distances at all displayed math.

Comment: No, it's not the same distance lol. It's the NORMAL spacing used by amsart, but by no means does that mean that it's the SAME spacing at the rest of the document. Again, see answer below...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the normal `\abovedisplayskip` used by `amsart`, which is about 41% of the value used in the standard classes, 4.9pt against 12pt. The difference is really noticeable, but it's the AMS house style.

If you deem the value too small, change it: add

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
 \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{12pt plus 3pt minus 7pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt plus 3pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{6.5pt plus 3.5pt minus 3pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\abovedisplayskip}%
}
```

before `\begin{document}`. If you don't plan to typeset math in different font sizes, this should be sufficient.

[image]

In my opinion, all those long equations should be left aligned: the big chunks of white space on the left makes for difficult reading. The same for the `cases` environment.

Comment: Awesome answer, grazie mille. Also, by left aligned, do you mean with the zeroes on the left side, i.e. 0&=...?

Comment: @AlexD No, I see no need to align the = signs

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its working as expected to me, but if you want to adjust the spacing, you can use `\vspace{distance}`. The argument can be a number followed by its units, so if you wanted an extra millimeter of space, you would put `\vspace{0.1 cm}` before and after your cases environment.